# Refference JSON schema from "define" API YAML file in Postman instead of creating a variable with actual JSON

Tags: api, automated-tests, postman, jsonschema

I have an API in Postman that has defined JSON schemas for every request\response.
I also have a collection of tests that i use for testing this API.
But I don't know how to connect these two substances(things)
I have been searching for a solution for quite a while now and havent found an example set-up or a tutorial how? instead of creating a variable with actual schema in my test collection, I want to reuse already existing schema from API by $ref or some other link method.

This is my first question here, writing it just cause i haven't found a proper answer but functionality that i seek sounds really basic and logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update from Valentin Despa:

"Please note that the API definition is written in a specification like Open API (or similar). It is not the same as the JSON schema which refers to the response body only."

So we can't validate response using that schema.